# plotly rendering bug with python 3d plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I am using `plotly` and `python` to visualize 3D data and I encoutered a strange phenomenon when plotting some data. The following code visualizes data of the form `(3,20)` each for the direction x,y and z.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = np.array([
    [4.41568822e+05, 4.41568474e+05, 4.41567958e+05, 4.41567603e+05,
     4.41567249e+05, 4.41566952e+05, 4.41566619e+05, 4.41566324e+05,
     4.41566021e+05, 4.41565737e+05, 4.41565435e+05, 4.41565098e+05,
     4.41564807e+05, 4.41564472e+05, 4.41564121e+05, 4.41563860e+05,
     4.41563538e+05, 4.41563226e+05, 4.41562933e+05, 4.41562641e+05],
    [5.71148897e+06, 5.71148909e+06, 5.71148928e+06, 5.71148942e+06,
     5.71148955e+06, 5.71148967e+06, 5.71148981e+06, 5.71148993e+06,
     5.71149006e+06, 5.71149019e+06, 5.71149032e+06, 5.71149047e+06,
     5.71149060e+06, 5.71149076e+06, 5.71149093e+06, 5.71149106e+06,
     5.71149122e+06, 5.71149137e+06, 5.71149153e+06, 5.71149168e+06],
    [1.86559470e+02, 1.86547226e+02, 1.86529120e+02, 1.86516642e+02,
     1.86504156e+02, 1.86493615e+02, 1.86481706e+02, 1.86471064e+02,
     1.86460026e+02, 1.86449593e+02, 1.86438417e+02, 1.86425803e+02,
     1.86414828e+02, 1.86402073e+02, 1.86388572e+02, 1.86378511e+02,
     1.86366018e+02, 1.86353893e+02, 1.86342497e+02, 1.86331154e+02]])

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=data[0,:], y=data[1,:], z=data[2,:],
                                   mode='markers',
                                   marker=dict(size=3),
                                   )])

pio.show(fig, renderer='browser')
```

I have compared the result (top) below with a matplotlib plot of the same data (bottom).

[image]
[image]

The points that represent a relatively straight line are represented in Plotly in steps rather than in a line, and I don't really understand why.

Can someone explain to me why the points are displayed like this in plotly and how I can fix this problem?
I appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with how Plotly is interpreting your numpy array. Your arrays look to be nested which would explain why instead of plotly drawing the plot as a continuous line they are being rendered as steps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But each of keys x,y and z is a 1d array, so even when I change the input to lists the effect does not change.